Issue with `hbase:meta` region not online
The hbase master is not initialized the logs shows:
2024-08-06 13:53:49,324 INFO  [ProcExecTimeout] assignment.AssignmentManager: Found 0 OPEN regions on dead servers and 240 OPEN regions on unknown servers

2024-08-06 04:28:48,632 WARN  [master/groot:16000:becomeActiveMaster] master.HMaster: hbase:namespace,,1650003038679.d8ca96dfa7bc436291f544e78688d3bf. is NOT online; state={d8ca96dfa7bc436291f544e78688d3bf state=OPEN, ts=1722932865164, server=hulk.mcloud.com,60020,1722236433701}; ServerCrashProcedures=false. Master startup cannot progress, in holding-pattern until region onlined.

also, I run commands in hbase shell un assign and assign, but it's not working.

Running hbase shell assign/unassign won't work without an active master.
I managed to fix this using hbck2, suggested in this Cloudera post.
Install hbck2
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/hbase/hbase-operator-tools-1.2.0/hbase-operator-tools-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzf hbase-operator-tools-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz

hbck assigns
Run hbck assigns, with region name of hbase:namespace, in your case d8ca96dfa7bc436291f544e78688d3bf
hbase hbck -j ~/hbase-operator-tools-1.2.0/hbase-hbck2/hbase-hbck2-1.2.0.jar assigns d8ca96dfa7bc436291f544e78688d3bf

Check the master logs: if you see assignment.AssignmentManager: Failed, followed by set override to by-pass state checks, using the --override flag to ignore other procedure locks.
hbase hbck -j ~/hbase-operator-tools-1.2.0/hbase-hbck2/hbase-hbck2-1.2.0.jar assigns d8ca96dfa7bc436291f544e78688d3bf --override

More guidance in the hbck2 README.
